# How to insert a “¾” into a Word doc?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, symbols

How do I insert a Unicode `¾` into a Word doc, either using symbols or unicode? I have tried going to “Insert > Symbols > Math Operators” and looking on the net for the unicode for `¾`.

Comment: Are you on macOS or Windows? Have you seen [this Microsoft support document on inserting symbols in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-symbol-in-word-2a061ae9-5a6c-4407-b618-8dc3c9fd4f44)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Fractions should automatically switch to that format as you type.

Just type `3/4` and it should convert to `¾`. You can toggle this feature in “File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options” choose the “AutoFormat as You Type” tab and look under “Replace as you type” there is a checkbox related to fractions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [official Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-symbol-in-word-2a061ae9-5a6c-4407-b618-8dc3c9fd4f44), those fractions can be found under “Insert > Symbol > More Symbols”

> Fractions (1/3, 2/5)
>
> Some fractions (1/4, 1/2, and 3/4) automatically switch to a fraction character (¼, ½, ¾) when you type them. But others do not (1/3, 2/3, 1/5, etc.) so if you want to insert those as symbols you'll need to use the insert symbol process.
>
> 1. Click or tapwhere you want to insert the fraction.
> 2. Go to **Insert > Symbol > More Symbols**.
> 3. In the **Subset** dropdown, choose **Number Forms**.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, press the 'alt' button and at the same time type 0190, it automatically types ¾. ½ is 0189 and ¼ is 0188. there are loads more, but I don't have room here to copy them all!